# FFT outptut for a signal with 2 cosf() cycles

Tags: fft, waveform, frequency-analysis

I am transforming a signal using the [ZeroFFT](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ZeroFFT) library. The results I get from it, are not what I would intuitively expect.

As a test, I feed the FFT algorithm with a buffer that contains two full cycles of cosine:

[image]

Which is sampled over 512 samples.

Which are fed as `int16_t` values. What I expected to get back, is 256 amplitudes, with the values `[ 0, 4095, 0, 0, ..., 0 ]`.

Instead, this is the result:
`2 2052 4086 2053 0 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 4 4 3 4...`

And it gets weirder! If I feed it the **same signal, but shifted** (so `sinf()` over 0 .. 4*pi instead of `cosf()` function) I get a completely different result: `4 10 2 16 2 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 2 4 3 4`

This throws up the questions:

**1**. Doesn't a sine signal and cosine signal with same period, contain exactly the same frequencies?

**2**. If I feed it a buffer with exactly 2 cycles of cosine, wouldn't the Fourier transform result in all zeros, except for 1 frequency?

I generate my test signal as:

```
static void setup_reference(void)
{
  for (int i=0; i<CAPTURESZ; ++i)
  {
    const float phase = 2 * 3.14159f * i / (256.0f);
    reference_wave[i] = (int16_t) (cosf(phase) * 0x7fff);
  }
}
```

And call the [ZeroFFT function](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ZeroFFT/blob/master/Adafruit_ZeroFFT.h#L56) as:

```
ZeroFFT(reference_Wave, CAPTURESZ);
```

Note: the ZeroFFT docs state that a Hanning window is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windowing causes some spectral leakage. Including the window function, the wave now looks like this:

[image: windows cosine]

> If I feed it a buffer with exactly 2 cycles of cosine, wouldn't the Fourier transform result in all zeros, except for 1 frequency?

Yes, if you do it without windowing. Actually two frequencies: both the positive frequency that you expect, and the equivalent negative frequency, though not all FFT functions will include the negative frequencies in their output (for Real input, the result is Hermitian-symmetric, there is no extra information in the negative frequencies). For practical reasons, since neither the input signal nor the FFT calculation are exact, you may not get exactly *zero* everywhere else either, but it should be close - that's mainly a concern for floating point output.

By the way by this I don't mean that windowing is bad, but in this special case (perfectly periodic input) it didn't work out in your favour.

As for the sine wave, the magnitudes of the result should be similar (within reason - exactness shouldn't be expected), but the comments on the FFT function you used mention

> The complex portion is discarded, and the real values are returned.

While phase shifts would not change the magnitudes much, they change the phases of the results, and therefore also their Real component.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. If I don’t throw away imaginary part, and  take length of (R,Im) instead then my issue (1) disappears? Because when the putput is shifted, how will I ever know which freqs are present?

Comment: @Bram yes, to be clear the outputs would not move to different indexes, but if you think of them in Polar form, their angle changes. Taking the magnitude gets rid of that angle.

Comment: Wouldn't ZeroFFT be a lot more useful if it did **not** discard the complex part? What would the rationale be for only using the real part? The author is Adafruit, which is an electronics company that sells, among others, microphones and microcontrollers. If you want to determine frequencies from a microphone, would the Real part really be enough?

Comment: @Bram that doesn't make any sense to me so far. FFT naturally computes both real and imaginary parts, that function then throws away the imaginary part and puts a comment `// discard imaginary phase val` - which doesn't actually make sense. The phase is encoded in the angle, not the imaginary part, and outputting just the real part of the FFT result is just strange. The result naturally ends up being real if the input signal was even (symmetric like cosine), which explains how that case in your code worked. But otherwise, just the real part is not super useful by itself AFAIK.

Comment: That code takes the absolute value of the Real part, which IDK, it feel like I'm being trolled by that code or something: the magnitude of a complex number is also called its absolute value, and computing *that* would make sense. Absolute value of the real part, not so much.